# How to hide divs when radio button is checked on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have an existing jquery code where it hides divs if the radio button is selected. However, when the page loads.. if this radio button is already checked, I want to be able to hide divs without clicking anything.

```
<script>
    $('input[name=resident]').click(function () {
            if (this.id == "residentNo") {
                $(".d").hide('slow');
                $('.d').find('#precinctNum').val('');
                $('.d').find('#yearStartedLiving').val('');                 
            } else {
                $(".d").show('slow');
                $('.d').find('#precinctNum').val('');
                $('.d').find('#yearStartedLiving').val('');
            }
        });     
</script>
```

html form:

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class = "res" id = "residentYes" name="resident" value="Yes" checked> Yes</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class = "res" id = "residentNo"  name="resident" value="No" > No</label>

<div class="d item form-group" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Precinct Number <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="precinctNum" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-12" name="precinctNum" data-validate-length-range="7" required="required" type="number">
</div>
</div>

<div class="d item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Start of Residency (Year) <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" id="yearStartedLiving" name="yearStartedLiving" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-12" required="required" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999'">
</div>
</div>
```

I've been trying for hours and it doesn't seem to work. Your help will be much appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // Will check after DOM is ready
        if($('#residentNo').is(':checked')){  // Check if residentNo is checked
        toggleDiv("residentNo")   
        }
      });


    $('input[name=resident]').click(function () {
    toggleDiv(this.id)

    })

    function toggleDiv(id){
                if (id == "residentNo") {
                    $(".d").hide('slow');
$(".d").find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving, #birthplace, #weight, #height, #income').val('');

                } else {
                    $(".d").show('slow');
$(".d").find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving, #birthplace, #weight, #height, #income').val('');

                }
            };
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dr4mznkr/9/)

NOTE: In this example I have set `residentNo` to `checked` to demo it

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Finally, my problem was solved thanks to you!! My team mates says thank you too.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff please consider accepting it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below. Just add the code in `$(document).ready`. Hope it helps.

```js
if($('#residentNo').is(':checked')){
    $(".d").hide();
    $('.d').find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving').val('');
}

$('input[name=resident]').click(function () {
     if (this.id == "residentNo") {
         $(".d").hide('slow');
         $('.d').find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving').val('');               
     } else {
         $(".d").show('slow');
         $('.d').find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving').val('');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class = "res" id = "residentYes" name="resident" value="Yes" checked> Yes</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class = "res" id = "residentNo"  name="resident" value="No" > No</label>

<div class="d item form-group" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Precinct Number <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="precinctNum" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-12" name="precinctNum" data-validate-length-range="7" required="required" type="number">
</div>
</div>

<div class="d item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Start of Residency (Year) <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" id="yearStartedLiving" name="yearStartedLiving" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-12" required="required" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999'">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the code can be shortened to 
`$('.d').find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving, #birthplace, #weight, #height, #income').val('');`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my answer. @mylee

Comment: It didn't work but I did shorten my code thanks to your suggestion. I didn't know this was possible! Thank you again.

Comment: Obviously it is possible. I've updated my answer with full code. @WandaMaximoff

Comment: More optimization by caching the 6 times called query. `var d = $(".d");`

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the event click on field of your interest:

```
$('input[name=resident][value="No"]').trigger('click');
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name=resident]').click(function () {
    if (this.id == "residentNo") {
      $(".d").hide('slow');
    } else {
      $(".d").show('slow');
    }
    $('.d').find('#precinctNum, #yearStartedLiving').val('');
  });
  
  
  $('input[name=resident][value="No"]').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class = "res" id = "residentYes" name="resident" value="Yes" checked> Yes</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class = "res" id = "residentNo"  name="resident" value="No" > No</label>

<div class="d item form-group" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Precinct Number <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input id="precinctNum" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-12" name="precinctNum" data-validate-length-range="7" required="required" type="number">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Start of Residency (Year) <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="yearStartedLiving" name="yearStartedLiving" class="form-control col-md-5 col-xs-12" required="required" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! I have solved the problem already but thank you. This will serve as a future reference for me and for others. Thank you!!!

Comment: very kind from your part. Thanks so much